# Can “lackadaisical” be used in literature?

Tags: history, formality, quotations, literature, literary-english

Has *lackadaisical* ever been used in literary works?  My *Oxford Dictionary of Quotations* has no quotation that includes this word.

Who first used *lackadaisical* in the 1760s as the OED claims?

Comment: The Oxford Dictionary of Quotations is not a compendium of all words used in English literature, and the absence of a word within it is no indication that it is not used in literature. There are quite a few [uses in Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lackadaisical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clackadaisical%3B%2Cc0), which would be a good place to start looking for examples.

Answer (score 4):

The earliest appearance of the term in a Google Books search is this one from [*Letters From Yorick to Eliza*](http://books.google.com/books?id=Kmk9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA173&dq=%22lackadaisical%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GRM2U4wfg4bIAZi4gbAM&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAzgy#v=onepage&q=%22lackadaisical%22&f=false), by Laurence Sterne:

> When I mounted my hobby horse, I never thought, or pretended to think, where I was going, or whether I should return home to dinner or supper, or the next day, or the next week. I let him take his own course; and amble, or curvet, or trot, or go a sober, sorrowful, **lackadaysical** pace, as it pleased him best. It was all one to me, for my temper was ever in unison with his manner of coursing it — be it what it might, I never pricked him with a spur, or struck him with a whip; but let the rein lay loosely on his neck, and he was wont to take his way without doing injury to any one.

According to [TristramShandyWeb.com](http://www.tristramshandyweb.it/sezioni/e-text/letter_parodies_double/letter_1.htm), Sterne wrote these letters in 1767, but they were published posthumously (he died in 1768). The edition that Google Books has in its database is dated 1797, but I believe that the first edition came out no later than the 1770s.

The first Google Books match for *lackadaisical* spelled in the modern way is from significantly later, in a novel attributed to "An Old-Fashioned Englishman" [actually Mrs. Barbara Holland], *[Says She to Her Neighbour, What?](http://books.google.com/books?id=KlAMAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA20&dq=%22lackadaisical%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Bxw2U6uVCMblyQHQjYGYCg&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAzhG#v=onepage&q=%22lackadaisical%22&f=false)* volume 2 (1815):

> You may think what you please, ladies ; but if you do not admire- my grandfather, you may be very dashing, very knowing, very quizzing, nay, even very sentimental, very **lackadaisical**, very romantic and novelistic, but depend upon it,- with all this, you know nothing of love, as a sublime and virtuous emotion, an ennobling and endearing principle, nor will you ever be able to comprehend the innumerable beauties in the song of Darby and Joan, for which I am extremely sorry, for I heartily wish every young lady of my acquaintance to understand it, and every married lady to experience it.

Thereafter, the occurrences of *lackadaisical* come thicker and faster.

Answer (score 2):

> **Lackadaisical**. A curious word—how has it origin- ated? Perhaps as the designation of one who was continually crying "A-lack-a-day!"
>   which means "a lack (a loss) to-day!" Or it may be connected with
>   "alas-the-day" (French hilas, Latin lassus, wearied). There seems no
>   possibility of arriving at any certainty as to the derivation.

-Origins and meanings of popular phrases & names, ... . Hargrave, Basil.

"**A-lack-a-day!"**:

**When Johnny comes marching home, three act military spectacular comic opera**. Book and lyrics by Stanislaus Stangé. by Edwards, Julian, 1855-1910.

**The Shakespeare garden club, a fantasy**, by Mabel M. Moran ...
by Moran, Mabel M.

&

**lackadaisical**

> [(adj.) Look up lackadaisical at Dictionary.com
>       1768 (Sterne), from interjection lackadaisy "alas, alack" (1748), an alteration of lack-a-day (1690s), from alack the day (1590s).
>   Hence, "given to crying 'lack-a-day,' vapidly sentimental." Sense
>   probably altered by influence of lax. Related: Lackadaisically.

**upsy-daisy** (adv.)

> ```
> 1711, up-a-daisy, baby talk extension of up (adv.). Compare lackadaisical. A word upsee was in use in English late 17c. in phrases
> ```
>
> such as upsee-Dutch "in the Dutch style" (of drinking), from Dutch op
>   zijn, and also occasionally as an adverb, "extremely," and could have
>   had an influence on this word.

-http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Lackadaisical.&searchmode=none